# Sql query pivot is too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying improve a SQL Query, and after run the execution plan, I created the Index-Non-Clustered for the principal table and now is taking less time, but the query is still slow.

```
SELECT  
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        i.CodigoInstalador as Code,
        e.Nombre,
        t.TipoOrden as OrderType,
        dbo.TotalValulaadic_codigoi(CodigoInstalador,@From,@To) as ValvulaAdic,
        dbo.TotalHechuraadic_codigoi(CodigoInstalador,@From,@To) as HechuraAdic
    FROM 
        Orden_Instalacion  i 
            LEFT JOIN Empleado e 
                on e.Codigo = i.CodigoInstalador
            LEFT JOIN Orden_Instalacion_Detalle d 
                on d.IdInstalacion = i.IdInstalacion 
            LEFT JOIN Orden_Tipo t 
                on t.IdTipoOrden = d.IdTipoOrden 
    WHERE  
        i.IdRegion = @idRegion AND 
        i.FechaInstalacion >= @FromAND 
        FechaInstalacion<=@To
        AND Ejecutado = 1
    ) AS ps
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT (OrderType)
        FOR TipoOrden IN
        ( 
            [Instalacion medidor proporcionado por usuario]
            ,[Instalation 1/2'' MyCo]
            ,[Instalation valvula 3/4'' MyCo]
            ,[Instalation box]
        )
    ) AS pvt
```

Exist a way to replace the pivot to improve the query or what other thing I can do?

Comment: Change `select *` to the columns you actually want. That will probably help a lot. You didn't say anything about indexes on the other three tables. I kind of have a feeling the pivot isn't really the problem. How fast is it without the pivot at the end?

Comment: @shawnt00 it's still taking the same time

Comment: I just noticed those two function calls (TotalValulaadic_condigoi, TotalHechuraadic_codigoi). Those could definitely be to blame.

Comment: Try commenting those two columns with the function calls and check the time again. It doesn't look like they're used again so the query should still work. Also I think you can try commenting out some of the joins to other tables to see which ones are making it slower. And since you already looked at the execution plan you might consider posting that.